# AngularJS Service - Extending objects of a passed object

Tags: angularjs, service

I have a schedule object that when I receive from my API has the following structure:

```
schedule : {
    id,
    name,
    day,
    month,
    year,
    shifts : [
        {
            id, 
            user,
            tasks : [...]
        }
    ]
}
```

I created three `services`: `Schedule`, `Shift`, and `Task`. For instance, my `Schedule` service is

```
app.factory('Schedule', function()
{
    return function() {
        // my methods here such as:

        this.save = function();
        this.remove = function();
        this.createShift = function();
        this.registerShift = function(shift);
    }
});
```

I want these services to extend my original object that I receive from the API, so that my `schedule` would then become:

```
schedule : {
    id,
    name,
    day,
    month,
    year,
    shifts,
    this.save = function(),
    this.remove = function(),
    this.createShift = function(),
    this.registerShift = function(shift)
}
```

Right now, the only way I can think of doing this is

```
angular.extend(scope.schedule, new Schedule());
```

But, it would be nicer, if I could pass the `schedule` to my Service, and assign it back and have all the original objects preserved, i.e. :

```
scope.schedule = new Schedule(scope.schedule);
// And all the attributes such as name, id, day, month, year are also returned back
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want a deep or shallow copy?

Comment: Deep copy.  I want all the collection from the original object.,  but with the added methods from my service.  That's why I am currently using the `extend ` to add the new methods

Comment: I know that angular.copy can be used for deep copy - i don't know if it will preserve extra properties that exist on one but not the other.

Comment: I don't see how that would help me? I edited my post a bit. I want the `schedule` to contain all its original keys, and then also have the new methods provided by the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the best way, but I ended up using the following (using underscore):

```
app.factory('Schedule', function()
{
    return function(schedule) {
        // This adds all the key => value pairs to 'this'
        var self = this;
        _.each(schedule, function(value, key)
        {
           self[key] = value;
        }); 

        this.save = function();
        this.remove = function();
        this.createShift = function();
        this.registerShift = function(shift);
    }
});
```

Then in my directive, I go

```
scope.schedule = new Schedule(scope.schedule);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Ctrl($scope,Shedule){
  $scope.schedule = {
    id,
    name,
    day,
    month,
    year,
    shifts : [
        {
            id, 
            user,
            tasks : []
        }
    ]
 };
// pass schedule object as a parameter
Shedule.processShedule.call($scope.schedule);
}

service:

app.service('Shedule',function()
{
    this.processShedule=function(obj){
         //you can access your parent object using self variable
         var self=obj;
         self.name="xyz";
         self.year="2014";
    }
}
```